# How get the username and birthday with the Facebook SDK for Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the Facebook SDK 3.14 and cant get the username and the birthday.

The user name should be public, but it returns null.

For date of birth I'm adding extra permissions but it still returns null.

My code is:

```
public class FacebookLoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements Session.StatusCallback {

/* ******************************
 ******* CONSTANTS **************
 * **************************** */
private static final String TAG = "TAG_FacebookLoginActivity";

/**
 * additional permissions.
 * the basic permissions are granted by default
 */
private final List<String> PERMISSIONS =
        Arrays.asList("email","user_birthday","public_profile");


/* ******************************
 ******* FIELDS *****************
 * **************************** */
private UiLifecycleHelper mUiLifecycleHelper;

/* ******************************
 ******* METHODS ****************
 * **************************** */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_login);
    mUiLifecycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, this);
    mUiLifecycleHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initViews();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mUiLifecycleHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mUiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mUiLifecycleHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mUiLifecycleHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mUiLifecycleHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        getUserInformation(session);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private void getUserInformation(Session session) {
    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Birthday: "+user.getBirthday());
            Log.d(TAG, "UserName: "+user.getUsername());

        }
    }).executeAsync();
}

/**
 * Initialize all views
 */
private void initViews() {
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    // request more permissions
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
}
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using v1 or v2 of the Graph API? If you are using v2 username is not available

Comment: I am using the Graph API v2. Is it possible to get the username differently?

Comment: No, username is not available anywhere. If you find it that is a bug so please tell me so we can remove it